# Part of my page not presented properly on safari browser

Tags: javascript, css, safari

My keyboard is showing as I wanted it to on Chrome and Firefox, but when I try it on Safari (on the phone!) looks like it does not make the width of the keys responsive. They stay the same width and then some of them are pushed to the next line. How can I rectify this?

html

```
<div class="play-area">
            <div id="key-container"></div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#key-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 123px;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: auto;
}

#key-container button {
    height: 35px;
    width: 6%;
    max-width: 55px;
    margin: 3px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #2525253c;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
  
#key-container button:active {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #00c8ff;
}

#key-container button:disabled {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000000, #00c8ff);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #ffffff;
}
```

JS

```
function createKeys() {

const keyboard = document.querySelector("#key-container");
const keys = [
    "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p",
    "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l",
    "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m"
];

keys.forEach(key => {
    const buttonElement = document.createElement("button");
    const insertLineBreak = ["p", "l"].indexOf(key) !== -1;
    buttonElement.textContent = key;
    buttonElement.setAttribute("id", key);
    buttonElement.addEventListener('click', () => handleClick(key));
    keyboard.appendChild(buttonElement);

    if (insertLineBreak) {
        keyboard.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Have you got a viewport meta tag set? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: I do have, yes. This is what I have: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: What have you got rem set as, and what is the width in CSS pixels of the phone you are using.

Comment: Sorry Haworth, not sure what you are asking. rem of what? How do I check the width in CSS pixels of the phone I am using?

Comment: You have set font size in rem units. The width in css pixels will be published, or you could use JavaScript to see what 100vw maps to.